# Unity resize screen when android keyboard appears

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mobile, keyboard

I'm actually creating a simple game for android devices with unity.

In the game, the player has to write a number.

So i use the input field object from unity UI.

When i use it on my device i got a weird thing;

When the android keyboard appears, unity resize the screen.

And when the keyboard disappears, unity resize again the screen into a normal mode, but when it does this, it's Absolutely ugly! (i see some weird artefacts during the process (in milliseconds), but it's very ugly).

I would like to know if i can order to unity to no resize anything, so the view remains the same with or without keyboard?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I can tell you it's perfectly possible, though I don't remember how. I'll check my projects when I get home and post back if someone else hasn't answered by then.

Comment: Still nothing? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry it took me days to post back, but I couldn't find it in my source files before, as I was looking in the wrong place. You'll see why in a moment. Here's what you need to do:

1. Assuming you don't have a custom AndroidManifest.xml in your project (if you do, skip to 4), make a build of your game.
2. Open your project's folder. Go to Temp/StagingArea and open AndroidManifest.xml in your editor of choice. Copy the contents.
3. Inside Unity, in the root of your Assets folder, create a 'Plugins' folder. Inside, create an 'Android' folder. In this folder, create a new file called AndroidManifest.xml. Paste the contents of the file you grabbed from step 2 inside.
4. In your AndroidManifest.xml file, inside the activity tag, add this custom attribute: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" so the final tag will look something like this:

```xml
    <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
```

After you do this, the screen should keep its contents after the keyboard appears.

Note: Do ***NOT*** use the code I provided here. Follow the steps to get the correct base AndroidManifest.xml file for your version of Unity and edit that one. Also make sure to update your manifest files every time you update Unity to a newer version. They could change that file at any time, and not using the latest version will create undesirable and hard to track side effects in your application.

Comment: Good to know! Please use the green check mark to mark this as the accepted answer to let others know the question has been answered too.